# Can UNION cause table lock on MyIsam?

Tags: mysql, locking, union, myisam

I was wandering weather UNION can cause table lock? 
Data base works on MyIsam engine. 
I select 3 data pieces, from the same table and join them using UNION

```
select *
from table1
where date between '2015-07-01' and current_date() and id in ( 2281,6691, 77854, 65847) and ctry = 'USA'

union

select *
from table1
where date between '2015-07-01' and current_date() and id in ( 2281, 1111, 86785,62257) and ctry = 'CA'

union

select *
from table1
where date between '2015-07-01' and current_date() and id= 1759
```

Answer (score 1):

MYISAM follows Table level Locking and innodb follows row level locking.So, In your case you are joining 3 tables , MYISAM will lock 1 table and then for others...

Comment: Query is executed on one table only. Does it mean it will cause table lvl lock anyway?

Comment: Your question is not clear......
MyIsam has three files. where .myi has your indexes, .myd has your table datas and .frm has its table definition. So,It will lock table then same data then again lock .. and so...and then finaaly display union..

Comment: Sorry for that. Fortunately your comment made everything clear. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM will do a table level lock -- probably 3 times (1 per union).

The following indexes should make the query run faster:

```
INDEX(ctry, id, date)
INDEX(id, date)
```